# Why does this import statement error come for no reason?

Tags: typescript, next-auth

I am recently getting an error while developing an API for an e-commerce site. I often get this import statement error which is the Prisma db is in the right path of folder structure or name but I get this error often which I can't move further development.

I need an answer / solution for this above statement.

```
import prisma from "@app/prismadb"
```

```
Cannot find module '@app/prismadb' or its corresponding type declaration
```

The error I am getting. It's the correct file path.

Comment: Apparently not correct enough for TypeScript to find it. For TS to find that path, there must be a folder named `@app` in `node_modules`, or you must have defined an alias to a local folder named `@app`. Within that folder must exist either a file named `prismadb.ts` or `prismadb.d.ts` or there must be a folder named `prismadb` within which there is a file named `index.ts` or `index.d.ts`. With the amount of information given, we can't help. Provide your package.json and tsconfig.json contents (as text, formatted as code) in the question. See [mre] for more tips.

Comment: yeah i resolved the matter for the problem statement .. while your using @(paths) the code didnt know what path we r refering into .. so i managed to get my prismadb path by giving this change of dirrectory which is ( ../your path ../ your path../)

by this method you can resolve that error